# The ideal of an affine variety is always radical?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading a note on Algebraic Geometry and it says that the ideal $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$ of an affine variety $\mathbb{V}(I)$ is always radical, i.e. it is an ideal equals to its radical ideal. The proof goes like if $f^m (a)=f(a)^m=0$ for some $a\in \mathbb{V}(I)$, then $f(a)=0$ and thus $f\in \mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$. I am kind of confused about why we have the equality $f^m (a)=f(a)^m=0$ here?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are working in the classical language of algebraic geometry. It's just merely observing that by definition

$$\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))=\{f\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]:f(x)=0\text{ for all }x\in \mathbb{V}(I)\}$$

But, note that if $f^m$ is in $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$, then for all $x$ in $V(\mathbb{I})$ one has that $f^m(x)=0$. But, by definition, $f^m(x)$, the $m$th power of $f$ evalued at $x$, is $f(x)^m$. So, we see that $f(x)^m=0$. Since we're working in a field this implies that $f(x)=0$. Since $x$ was aribtrary we see that $f$ is in $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$. Since $f$ was arbitrary we deduce that $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$ is radical as desired.